# Is there a way to fix cut-off text in a PDF file?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I have a library manual that the creator changed some of the LaTeX code and changed the page position and size, but didn't check it before compiling, distilling and sending it off.  He is currently unavailable, so if I want to print it I have to fix it myself.

I was able to use some ghostscript commands to push the entire text down to something approaching centered on the page, the command is show below:

```
/usr/bin/gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o /home/user/shiftdown.pdf -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -c "<</PageOffset [0 -35]>> setpagedevice" -f /home/user/brokendoc.pdf
```

The issue is that while the page is now printable without hitting hardware margins, the chapter titles are still halfway cut off at the top.  If I open the PDF in Acrobat or Reader, I can select the chapter title and copy it and it pastes the full text in the program of my choosing.  When I tried printing it on a Xerox MFP with a partially incompatible driver it printed the header, but it wouldn't duplex and I didn't want to print 700+ pages and then use the copy to 1 -> 2 function.

Does anyone know of a way to fix these cut off headers such that they either appear correctly in the PDF file or at least reliably print correctly?  I have ghostscript easily available, TeX relatively easily available and the standard version of Acrobat X.

[update:]

After downloading the demo of Acrobat Pro XI, I was able to go to the "Print Production" tab and click on "Edit Object".  When I clicked on the cut off chapter titles it showed me two bounding boxes that covered the entire page with one just a little taller than the other.  When I right clicked on it I got the option to Add Clip and Delete Clip.  When I click on Delete Clip it shows the entire chapter title.  If I click on Add Clip it says, "One or more of the selected regions already have a clipping region.  Proceed with setting the clipping regions for the selected objects? [No] [Yes]"

With that added information, I know there has to be a way to in a batch mode fix the issue, anyone know what command translates into this?

Comment: As *without hitting hardware margins, the chapter titles are still halfway cut off*, this sounds like some clipping detail. Unfortunately clipping can be achieved either using `/CropBox` settings or clipping paths. You might want to search the ghostscript documentation for these keywords.

Comment: I think you are right, but all of my searches have come up pretty empty even using those terms.  This is definitely one of those fine details that doesn't seem to get covered very well.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing the 'brokendoc.pdf' it's hard to know. If I see the file, I can tell you what's going on, and (probably) how to fix it or work around it.

I don't need the entire file, so just a shortened version that only has a few pages that shows the problem will suffice. You might be able to get this from the complete brokendoc.pdf using:
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o part.pdf -dLastPage=10 brokendoc.pdf

Also, you may want to try:
 gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o fitted.pdf -dPDFFitPage -sPAPERSIZE=letter -dFIXEDMEDIA brokendoc.pdf

The above will scale (and center) the page on to the specified page size. You can specify 'letter' or 'a4' or use -dMEDIAWIDTHPOINTS=**_ -dMEDIAHEIGHTPOINTS=_** to get a specific output page size. The -dFIXEDMEDIA option causes gs to ignore the MediaBox in the file.

Comment: The FIXEDMEDIA command seemed to have no effect.  I'm trying to figure out where to put the file such that it is accessible since my company blocks all of the various file sharing services.  The version of the file that is on the [internet](http://www.boeing.com/phantom/socs/docs/SOCS_Users_Guide.pdf) is old by a .1 revision, but it also doesn't have the issue.

Comment: I downloaded the acrobat pro demo and used edit object.  When I right clicked on it there were two boxes and I could click on "delete clip".  That removes the region that is covering up the top.  Now I just need to figure out how to do it in batch mode.